# отображение данных в StatusBar

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

У меня есть два таблицы у обоих есть ячейка BSONUM, при нажатии в DBGrid в StatusBar отобразить значение от второй таблице CLASS если значение BSONUM=BSONUM

```
  qry6.Active:=False;
  qry6.SQL.Text:='SELECT top 1 * from SEGMENTS where BSONUM='+#39+qry1.FieldByName('BSONUM').AsString+#39;
  //Clipboard.AsText:=qry6.SQL.Text;
  qry6.Active:=True;
  if qry6.RecordCount>=1 then
  stat1.Panels.Items[9].Text:='Класс = '+qry6.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('CLASS').AsString;
```

при нажатии в DBGrid выходит такая ошибка, помогите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверь, что возвращает вот эта строка qry6.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('CLASS')

Comment: 99% что `qry6.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('CLASS')  = nil`.